# What is the best practices as to cropping the positive examples for training hog classifier?

Tags: feature-selection, train, computer-vision

I've been reading up on the literature on HOG training, but I can't figure out what the best practices are for cropping the positive examples.

**Question:** Do you crop tight or with margins on the “object”? Do you crop all positive image to a standard aspect ratio or to whatever rectangle fits the appearance of the object in the particular image?

Comment: I'm new here, is the best place to ask this type of question, if not where?

Comment: I guess I should try another site....